# IntelliJ Idea 13.1.4 gradle build

Tags: gradle, intellij-13

I am trying to build a project with gradle from within Intellij Idea 13.1.4 (commercial edition) However all files from WEB-INF directory apart from web.xml does not appear in the web facet

Everything was working fine in 13.1.3

Comment:
I have already found an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127582) logged against the IntelliJ.

Comment: This is incomplete. Are you really building it using Gradle or building it in IJ using a project imported from Gradle? What version of Gradle? How does you `build.gradle` looks like?

Comment: Same problem here. Using gradle wrapper 1.11. I have web application without web.xml, using spring WebApplicationInitializer. Opening project as gradle project fails to recognize src/main/webapp folder as web app root in Web Facet config, have to configure it manually, but every time Idea is restarted, it refreshes gradle project and removes manualy set webapp path.

Answer (score 1):

Known bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127693 .

Downgrade to 13.1.3: http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-13.1.3.dmg .

Comment: Known bug, here is the link to roll back to 13.1.3Known bug:  Downgrade to 13.1.3: http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-13.1.3.dmg .